# MVC4: ModelState not valid when passing null for Nullable field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

I am creating a menu-structure with submenus.
TopMenu-Items should have a ParentID of NULL

My Model:

```
    public Menu()
    {
        this.active = true;
        this.publishStart = DateTime.Now;
        this.seq = 1;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Name_Sub { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Menu Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> ChildMenus { get; set; }
```

and

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().HasOptional(s => s.Parent)
   .WithMany(s => s.ChildMenus).HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentID);
```

when updating a topLevel Menu (ParentID=null) through JSon, my ModelState is invalid because of ParentID = null

I could solve it with a ParentID = 0 for Top-Level, but I would like to know the reason why Null fails, although I made it NULLABLE in the model.

Comment: The exact error you're getting would be helpful...

Comment: Do you have a custom model binder? The default model binder handles this scenario without any issues so my 1st guess is that you're using some sort of a custom model binder...

Comment: It's a good question, but at StackOverflow you really need to stand by and respond to comments quickly.

Comment: Try to use `Nullable<int>` instead of `int?`

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the return value "null" instead of "" (empty string).
I am using jtable (jtable.org) and created a custom display field for ParentID, which caused the problem, as I showed the ParentIDs (1,2,....44..) and "null" on top Level.
So "null" got posted back, where it should have been ""